# query xml powershell sharepoint

Tags: powershell, query

```
Get-SPSite mysite |
Select -ExpandProperty AllWebs |
Select -ExpandProperty Lists |
Select -ExpandProperty Items |
Out-File outputpm.txt
```

I have this code, which produces the items, one of the items is xml which can be expanded. There is a part in the xml which I want to query, so it filters down the list I already have.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what you are trying to do, what I can decipher is that you want all lists of a SPSite which contains any item with the Title 'M' (guessing at Title)?

Comment: no there is something in the XML item I want to query.

Comment: the xml item is large so i'll just give one bit that it contains ows_FolderChildCount='3;#0'

Comment: so for all items in my site I want to query the XML where 
ows_FolderChildCount='3;#0'

Comment: What is '3;#0' anyway? I suspect it means $someItem["FolderChildCount"] is 0, but you need the '3', what is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably not the fastest solution, but it should work:

```
Get-SPSite mysite |
select -ExpandProperty AllWebs |
select -ExpandProperty Lists |
select -ExpandProperty Items |
? { ([xml]$_.Xml).row.ows_FolderChildCount -eq "3;#0" }
```

You could perhaps solve this with `SPQuery`, although I'm not sure how.